# How do I reduce the amount of faces in the most fluent way possible?

Tags: modeling, topology, retopology

I've been re-topologizing a character for quite a while and everything seems to be working out until I get to the hands.

[image]

There's a problem where I have too much faces to connect the arm with. What's the most effective way to 'reduce' the amount of faces so I could connect the hand and arm together?

Thanks

Link to arm - https://pasteall.org/blend/1b7b52d8fb0040b2944db8b7068b8f03

Comment: hello, please share this part of your object so that we can propose something: nhttps://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Obligatory link to Topology guides: https://topologyguides.com/loop-reduction :))

Comment: Thanks, Jachym!

Comment: Hey moonboots, this is the link to the arm. https://pasteall.org/blend/1b7b52d8fb0040b2944db8b7068b8f03 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, here is one that reduces by half the amount of faces:

[image]

Comment: Ooh this is interesting. I probably should have taken account of the loops in the fingers ahha! Thanks!

Comment: the loops in the fingers? what do you mean?

Comment: Where the finger starts from the hands. I had four faces per side for each finger which might have complicated the process.